# Navigation in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, authentication, navigation, view

I am new in CakePHP. This is the navigation part I am using in 1 of my CakePHP websites :

```
<?php
       $list=array(
                $this->Html->link('Home',array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'index')),
                $this->Html->link('About',array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'about')),array(
                                                                                             $this->Html->tag('span',null,array('class'=>'top')),
                                                                                             $this->Html->tag('span',null,array('class'=>'bottom')),
                                                                                             $this->Html->link('Sub Menu 1',array('controller'=>'','action'=>'')),
                                                                                             $this->Html->link('Sub Menu 2',array('controller'=>'','action'=>'')),
                                                                                             $this->Html->link('Sub Menu 3',array('controller'=>'','action'=>'')),
                                                                                          ),
                $this->Html->link('Gallery',array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'gallery')),array(
                                                                                                 $this->Html->tag('span',null,array('class'=>'top')),
                                                                                                 $this->Html->tag('span',null,array('class'=>'bottom')),
                                                                                                 $this->Html->link('Sub Menu 1',array('controller'=>'','action'=>'')),
                                                                                                 $this->Html->link('Sub Menu 2',array('controller'=>'','action'=>'')),
                                                                                                 $this->Html->link('Sub Menu 3',array('controller'=>'','action'=>'')),
                                                                                              ),
                $this->Html->link('My Posts',array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'myPosts/1')),
                $this->Html->link('Blog',array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'blog')),
                $this->Html->link('Contact',array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'contact')),
                $this->Html->link('Logout',array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'logout'))
             );
       echo $this->Html->nestedList($list);
?>
```

What I want, "My Posts" and "Logout" menus will be shown if and only a user is logged in, otherwise not. How to do it ? And, do you have any better idea to make a navigation bar in CakePHP ?

Here `span` tags are used only for design issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1st Solution

You have to create a separate array for logged in user and this can be done via auth functions like

**In Controller**

```
$this->set('authUser', $this->Auth->user());
```

OR

```
$this->set( 'authUser', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
```

**In View**

```
If($authUser){
     $list = array(/*without Post and Logout*/);
} else{
     $list = array(/*same complete array*/);
}
```

### **2nd Solution**

```
if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')){
     $list = array(/*without Post and Logout*/);
} else{
     $list = array(/*same complete array*/);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say, I am using "Authentication" here for login,logout,signUp. Does "Session" work here ?

Comment: I've updated the answer please check. I hope this will work for you

Comment: Wow, its nice, I think it'll help me, I am gonna try it now. Thanks a lot friend.

Comment: Hey, I just tried it, but it shows an error, saying that it needs some "AuthHelper". As I know, there is no such helper, there is a component called "AuthComponent". When I include "Auth" helper in the $helpers variable of the Controller, it says that there is no such helper. Is there any function or something like "loggedIn())" or "user()" in "AuthComponent" or somewhere else ? I am using cakephp-2.3.6, may be there was an "Auth" helper in the previous versions. @Moyed Ansari

Comment: I used this code in 1 of my "View" files where I need the navigation bar ("header"): echo $this->element('header',array("authUser"=>$this->Auth->loggedIn()),array("cache"=>"long_view")); . So I think $authUser variable should be available in the "header.ctp" element and it should have the logged in user's name or something. But this is not the case here, it shows that the variable is not recognized in the "header.ctp" file. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: you asked two different questions. this would be helpful if you create a new question.  for first issue you need to add Auth component in your controller like this var $components = array( 'Auth')

Comment: I added the "Auth" component exactly like you said. But it requires "Auth" helper. And, I liked your solution, I tried to vote your answer, but I couldn't because of reputation, I need at least 15 reputation to vote. Is there any other way to like your answer ? @Moyed Ansari

Comment: I asked this question in the CakePHP community too, now waiting for a reply. @Moyed Ansari

Comment: is it still showing some error ? Right now you can accept answer only due to less reputation

Comment: Yeah, its still showing error. I don't understand what's wrong with $this->Auth->user() ? @Moyed Ansari